# How to use the value of one key in another in yaml file

Tags: python, yaml

I need to write a URL key in yaml file using another key of the same yaml file.

A: local

URL: https://login.{A}.domain.com/

While I read the file in my python script I should get

For A -- local

For URL -- https://login.local.domain.com/

How can I get the above output. Thank you for helping in advance.

Comment: There is nothing in YAML or Python which directly supports this. It's not hard to write Python code to replace keywords in strings, but you have to write it yourself, or at the very least some glue code to call a template processor or similar.

Comment: I second @tripleee comment, for example in `serverless` you can access other yaml variables like this `foo: ${self:bar.baz}`